# Why is my python datetime object (created from a timestamp) not automatically being created as UTC?

Tags: python

I'm grabbing a UTC timestamp from Javascript and passing it to my python code.  I want to store that date as a datetime, so I construct it with `dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(starttime) / 1000)`.  I check the timestamp and it is for 12:00 am UTC on a specific date.  However, when I print out this newly created datetime object, it prints as 19:00 from the day before.

There is clearly some timezone issues at work here, but I expect that the default should always be UTC (apparently I expect wrong).  How do I get this to always operate under UTC, rather than have some weird timezone transformation at play?

Comment: What does the `starttime` variable contain?

Comment: @DavidRobinson In one example, it contains 1408060800000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for `fromtimestamp` [states](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp) (emphasis mine):

> Return the local date and time corresponding to the POSIX timestamp, such as is returned by time.time(). If optional argument tz is None or not specified, **the timestamp is converted to the platform’s local date and time**, and the returned datetime object is naive.

Thus `fromtimestamp` does indeed return a value for your local timezone (not UTC as you expected). What you want is [utcfromtimestamp](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp):

```
starttime = 1408060800000
dt = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int(starttime) / 1000)

dt  # returns the UTC time you expected:
# datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 15, 0, 0)
```